# SQL Server 2008 Insert image into table without using BULK QUERY

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulk

I need to find another way to insert an image into a SQL Server table without using BULK Query. We cannot use BULK query due to our client's protocol which is not allowed to grant my user as sysadmin or bulkadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with C#? If so, you can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Assuming you are trying to run an insert like this:

```
insert into TableA (ImageColumn) values ( /* file contents */ )
```

You can replace it with code like this:

```
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"full path to file");
var record = new TableAs();
record.ImageColumn = fileContents;
TableAs.InsertOnSubmit(record);
SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to insert an Image to database without BULK query is encode the Image file to base64 format, and store it using normal sql insert query, and we can decode it whenever we need it in image format.